# How can I simplify the following CNF

Tags: discrete-mathematics, conjunctive-normal-form

(¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (¬p ∨ q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ r) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬r)

I could not simplify the above CNF. Could anyone please help me to simplify the statement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

We can make a truth table for this:

```
p   q   r   (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (¬p ∨ q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ r) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬r)
0   0   0   1
0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
0   1   1   0
1   0   0   1
1   0   1   0
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   0
```

If this truth table is correct, then an equivalent expression is:

```
(¬q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ q ∧ ¬r)
```

We can factor out to simplify a bit...

```
[¬q ∨ (p ∧ q)] ∧ ¬r
```

We can also recognize that ¬q ∨ (p ∧ q) = ¬q ∨ p ...

```
(¬q ∨ p) ∧ ¬r
```

This seems to match the truth table we got, so if that truth table is right, this expression is almost surely minimal or close to it. It only uses each variable once and so the only way that springs to mind to try to improve it is De Morgan, but it doesn't look like it reduces the number of operations even, so this might be as good as it gets.